# What is the best approach to handle a Outlook add-in Inspector UI contorl null reference exception caused by cancelling a long running async call?

Tags: async-await, outlook-addin

When user opens Outlook email item, my Outlook add-in creates an new Inspector in Outlook.Inspectors collection. To fill out Inspector form region user controls, few long running async DB calls are called. Generally, user can close email/Inspector window at any time while the async calls are running. The problem is the form region Close event occurs before async call completion. As a result, when async call is completed, my Inspector code tries to update form region user control but, by this moment, the control is null and disposed in form region Close event. Hence, null reference exception is thrown. 
I added some code in Inspector Close event where I set up an ad-hoc flag indicating that Inspector is closed. The flag value is checked up in a *catch(NullReferenceException)* block. If flag shows that email is closed, the null reference exception is ignored and a new OperationCancelledException is thrown to cancel other related running async calls. Although the code works, I am not sure that this is the best approach to handle the error this way. Firstly, although the flag indicates that email is closed, the null reference exception might not be neccessary related to disposed UI user control. Secondly, I need to add *catch(NullRefernceException)* block to try-catch block in all relevant methods.
If you've had a similar problem, would you be able to advise your solution, please?
Thank you.

Comment: Why not simply check that the particular object is null before even accessing it?

Comment: Yes, I can do this. The implication is a null reference check has to be added after every single await call where UI element is accessed. It is feasible but kind of cumbersome because UI element can be accessed first time after async call in some of the subsequently called methods.

Comment: I wouldn't say cumbersome, but rather defensive.

Comment: I meant, it would be a cumbersome solution for my code because it lacked clarity. It would be difficult for me to track first time access to a disposed UI user control in multiple logical branches after await call.

Comment: Then just check it only once and throw your own meaningful exception. Much better than a generic "null reference" exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of throwing and handling exceptions, I'd recommend keeping a dictionary of opened items, so you could easily detect whether a particular window is still opened. For example, you may develop an inspector wrapper - see [Implement a wrapper for inspectors and track item-level events in each inspector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-implement-a-wrapper-for-inspectors-and-track-item-level-events-in-each-inspector).

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. Actually, my inspectors have  wrappers. I added the aforementioned flag property the wrapper to indicate if related window is opened or closed. I think, this flag property is functioning similar to recommended dictionary of opened items.  Agree with you, I can use the flag directly without throwing exceptions. I assume, the implication of this solution is I have to check flag state after each await call to stop code execution continuation if email window is closed. Am I correct?

Comment: Sounds right. Or just try to use cancellation tokens to stop a background work if the item is closed.